# Registraton of ORMObjectListener with component framework

Tags: components, listener, intershop

I just tried to add registration of my custom ORMObjectListener with instances and implementations and it does not work. I can see that all system ORMObjectListener-s are registered in cartridge onReadyHook() metehod, but I like to try to register them with component framework.

I added following to implementations.component:

```
<implementation name="ProductPODeleteListener" class="hr.a1.orm.product.internal.ProductPODeleteListener" start="start" stop="stop" factory="JavaBeanFactory"/>
```

And following to instances.component:

```
<instance name="ProductPODeleteListener" with="ProductPODeleteListener" scope="global"/>
```

This is start method of ProductPODeleteListener:

```
public synchronized void start() {
    productFactory.addObjectListener(this);
}
```

But my custom listener is not registered (start method is never called).
I can see in log file that implementation is loaded on start:

```
"Adding implementation ProductPODeleteListener to configuration bc_a1_orm."
```

Did I do something wrong?

Maybe what is missing is a call to componentMgr.getGlobalComponentInstance("ProductPODeleteListener")?
As stated here: https://support.intershop.com/kb/index.php/Display/25G731#Concept-ComponentFramework-InGeneral -> "The ComponentFW will instantiate all defined instances on the first access." I don't think it's possible to register listeners with component framework, as those needs to be registered on server start. Is that correct?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are completely right. I tested this and the component is never initialized at server startup. Only if some other code request your component is it ever initialized. Global or app would not make a difference.

```
//get instance 
NamingMgr.getManager(ComponentMgr.class).getGlobalComponentInstance("ProductPODeleteListener");
//after this component is init & listeren is up
```

I guess this 'lazy loading' is done for performance reasons.

The best to me it seems is to load the listener with the `onPostStartup` method in the cartridge class. This one isn't deprecated and also doesn't seem that it will ever be.

```
public class CustomCartridge extends Cartridge
{
    @Override
    public boolean onPostStartup()
    {
        System.out.println("starting customer cartridge listener");

        ProductPOFactory productFactory = (ProductPOFactory)NamingMgr.getInstance().lookupFactory(ProductPO.class);
        productFactory.addObjectListener(new ProductPODeleteListener());

        return super.onPostStartup();
    }

}
```

In the cartridge's property file change the loading class to yours

```
################################################################################
# cartridge properties for cartridge CustomCartridge
################################################################################

intershop.cartridges.CustomCartridge.classname=com.example.capi.CustomCartridge
```

Comment: Yes, I ended up doing just that. Thank you!